# JavaScript-Creating a Function to capitalise the first letter of a string

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having trouble in creating a function to capitalise the first letter of a string. I can capitalise the string when I enter words in lowercase, but not in uppercase. I really appreciate some assistance with this problem, please see my script below:

```js
function captialise(str) {
    str = prompt("Enter a string");
    console.log(str[0].toUpperCase() + str.substring(1))
}

captialise();
```

Comment: You should force the rest of the string to lowercase: `+ str.substring(1).toLowerCase()`. Just like you did for the first letter.

Comment: Why do you expect a string as an argument and at the same time prompt a string? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: why minus from my answer.. when it's 100% correct.. the toxicity here is real

Comment: also the argument is completely useless but it isnt harming anything.. i think it's just the dude's style

Answer (score 2):

Uppercase the first character, *lowercase the rest*. The snippet uses a bit more modern scripting (the function uses a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals))

```js
const capitalize = str => str.slice 
  ? `${str.slice(0,1).toUpperCase()}${str.slice(1).toLowerCase()}` 
  : str;

const str1 = `someSTRING`; 
const str2 = `someotherstring`; 
const str3 = `s23omeotherstring`; 
const str4 = prompt('enter something'); 

console.log(capitalize(str1));
console.log(capitalize(str2));
console.log(capitalize(str3));
console.log(capitalize(str4));
```

Comment: Gives error if I enter something not a string. For example a number

Comment: Well it doesn't make sense to capitalize a number?

Comment: @mplungjan fair enough, edited answer. Numbers from a `prompt` will be return as a string btw.

Comment: @KooiInc true, but you did not have a prompt in your code before

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it, and I believe it was asked a lot of time here before,
This one is with one line:

```js
function captialise(str) {
    str = prompt("Enter a string");
    console.log(`${str[0].toUpperCase()}${str.substring(1).toLowerCase()}`);
  
}

captialise();
```

Answer (score 0):

The logical problem is that you're capitalising the first part yes, but you're NOT lowering the other parts

```js
function captialise(str) {
    str = prompt("Enter a string");
    console.log(str[0].toUpperCase() + str.substring(1).toLowerCase())
}

captialise();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to have a function return what you name it.

You need to lowerCase the rest of the string too and I would test you have a string in the first place

I chose to use + instead of template literals since it is easier to read in this simple case

```js
const captialise = str => str && typeof str === "string" ? 
  str.slice(0,1).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1).toLowerCase() : 
  str;


console.log(
   captialise(prompt("Enter a string"))
)
```